# Updating DataGrid from multiple threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid, timeout

I want to update my a DataGrid from multiple thread in WPF(c#). I use dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() and dataGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke() but they freeze program (main thread). How can update dataGrid from multiple threads with a timeout ( because I use web service that may be unreachable ).

Comment: I guess you are doing the web service call inside the method that is invoked by the Dispatcher. That will of course freeze the UI. Call the web service from the background thread (*before* calling `Invoke`) and only pass the result to the UI thread by `Invoke`.

Comment: Hi Clemens. Is it possible to show me an example? I'm new in multi threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the DataGrid editing to be done in the threads, you can run them in the main thread like this:

```
this.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
    //Edit the DataGrid however you like in here
});
```

Make sure to only put things you *need* to be run in the main thread inside it (otherwise that would defeat the purpose of multithreading).

Comment: -> your answer does not contain timeout. also it throw an exception. however thank you...

Comment: @Babak.Abad Really? What Exception does it throw? Because I've used that and it's always worked. And you'd put the timeout after the invoke so that it's run in the thread and not the main thread.

Comment: excuse me AlphaDelta. did you mean this.Dispatcher.Invoke(...) ?

Comment: I see no exception. But I see that my program is freezed. +1 for your help. if have other solutions please help me

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Task` kick off the web service request asynchronously. To do this you will probably need to convert the EAP (event-based asynchronous pattern) style into a TAP (task-based asynchronous pattern) style. Here is how you do that.

```
private Task<IEnumerable<YourDataItem>> CallWebServiceAsync()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
  var service = new YourServiceClient();
  service.SomeOperationCompleted +=
    (sender, args) =>
    {
      if (args.Error == null)
      {
        tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
      }
      else
      {
        tcs.SetException(args.Error);
      }
    };
  service.SomeOperationAsync();
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

After you have that in place then you can use the new `async` and `await` keywords to make the call and wait for it to return using continuation style semantics. It would look like this.

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  IEnumerable<YourDataItem> data = await CallWebServiceAsync();
  YourDataGrid.DataSource = data;
}
```

That is it! It does not get a whole lot more elegant than that. This will perform the operation asynchronously on a background thread and then bind the results to the `DataGrid` on the UI thread.

If the WCF service is unreachable then it will throw an exception and will be attached to the `Task` so that it propagates up to the `await` call. At that point it will be injected into the execution and can be wrapped with a `try-catch` if necessary.